# Qual a melhor forma, mudar somente as etapas do cadastro e nao toda pagina

Tags: jquery, slide

Tenho uma pagina onde o usuário opta por fazer login (caso já tiver cadastro) ou faz o cadastro, caso ele optar pelo cadastro ao clicar no botão `cadastre-se` gostaria que o elemento saísse para esquerda e a primeira etapa do cadastro viesse pela direita igual a um sistema de slide.

No meu html da Home eu tenho as etapas chamo cada uma através de um include e deixo uma baixo da outra seguindo a hierarquia, não sei se para o que eu quero essa é a melhor opção.

Tipo eu poderia usar `display:none` e aplicando `display:block` no próximo elemento. Mas gostaria de fazer o efeito `slide` alguém pode me dar uma luz e exemplos.

---

Segue um exemplo de um jeito simples que eu `poderia` fazer mas que quero substituir pelo efeito slide:

[Exemplo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1r3vwf30/embedded/result)

VLw

Comment: Amigo, faz um exemplo no jsFiddler para gente te ajudar. Você quer que cada passo a div desse passo tenha um efeito slide a direita, é isso?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1r3vwf30/embedded/result/   fiz um exemplo simples do jeito que eu poderia fazer,  mas gostaria de em vez de simplesmente sumir ele deslizasse para a esquerda e desse lugar para etapa2 que vai deslizar da direita. @RBoschini   tentei algumas coisas como como `.hide()` e `.show()` mas n deu muito certo e nem o `.animate({width: '0'} )` ...

Comment: @Erick, dá uma olhada em animate do jquery: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Deixei um exemplo no fiddler para vc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, fiz um exemplo para você.
Veja se ajuda

http://jsfiddle.net/qo7557p5/

Criei o html com os passos.

```
<div id="wizardSignin" data-step="1" active>
 <h1> Step 1 </h1>
 <input type="text">
</div>

<div id="wizardSignin" data-step="2">
 <h1> Step 2 </h1>
 <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div id="wizardSignin" data-step="3">
 <h1> Step 3 </h1>
 <select>
   <option>Option 1</option>
 </select>
</div>

 <input type="button" id="nextButton" value="next">
```

No Js, controlo exibição e aplico efeito de slide como você especificou.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[data-step]').hide();
  $('div[data-step=1]').show();

  $('#nextButton').on('click',function(){
        var idx  = $('#wizardSignin[active]').attr('data-step');
        $('#wizardSignin[active]').removeAttr('active').hide();

      if(idx<3){
        idx++;
      }else{
        idx=1;
      }

      $('#wizardSignin[data-step="'+idx+'"]').attr('active','');
      $('#wizardSignin[data-step="'+idx+'"]').effect('slide');


  });

});
```

Veja se isso ajuda.

Comment: Olha é bem isso, to tentando aplicar a minha necessidade aqui n estou conseguindo ao clicar no botão ele some com o primeiro elemento mas n mostra o segundo mas talvez eu esteja errando algo aqui o seu exemplo foi bacana muito obrigado.

Comment: Lembre-se que esse exemplo usa data-tag, nao esqueca de por o data-step nas suas divs.

Comment: Edita seu fiddler e posta aqui que eu ajudo vc, mas adapta antes aquele que vc ja enviou, assim podemos codar juntos.

Comment: Descobri o que eu tinha errado e agora funcionou, so vou precisar saber se vai me atender ja que o sisteminha e mais robusto do que citei... Mas enfim me foi util e funcionou muito obrigado.

Comment: é possível fazer o primeiro elemento deslizar para esquerda e o proximo vir da direita?

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar CSS para fazer isso. Usando CSS transition e margem negativa escondes o elemento. Depois adicionas uma classe que repõe a margem a zero, com JavaScript.

CSS

```
#slideleft {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  margin-left: -200px;
  background: #ccf;
}

.abrir {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  slide.classList.toggle('abrir');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/20b36dnv/

Comment: Tentei inverter deixando a caixa já aberta e ao clicar no botão ela deslizar mas n deu certo,  na vdd so invert o `margin-left:` no css, o que pode ser? Isso no seu exemplo no jsfiddle.

Comment: @Erick assim http://jsfiddle.net/20b36dnv/1/?